# find the average grade earned on the problem solving assessment.

Tags: statistics

A problem solving assessment was given to students at four area schools. Students at
Lincoln earned an average of 15 on the assessment. Students at Washington earned an average of 17.
Students at Jefferson earned an average of 14. Students at Adams earned an average of 16.

12. If Lincoln had 86 students, Washington had 112 students, Jefferson had 90 students, and Adams had 122
    students, find the average grade earned on the problem solving assessment.
13. If the standard deviation for Jefferson was 1.90, at least what percent of the students earned between
    9.725 and 18.275 on the assessment given at Jefferson?
14. If Washington had a standard deviation of 1.75, find the z-scores for the following students from
    Washington: Catherine: 20, Dakota: 18, Steven: 12, Cheri: 14

I am very sorry... but i am completely lost!!!!!  I have the answers, but no idea how they got them.

12. 15.62
13. 80.25%
14. Catherine: 1.71
    Dakota: 0.57
    Steven: -2.86
    Cheri: -1.71

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 12, you need to understand weighted average. Imagine every student at Lincoln scored $15$ etc.  What would the average be?  You have $86$ scores of $15$ and $\ldots$  For 13 and 14 you need to understand z scores.  Read your book or do some searches.

Comment: This was a last resort; I have done that. I did figure out 12 though, thanks.

Comment: For 13,you need to compute how many standard deviations below the mean 9.725 is and how many standard deviations above the mean 18.275 is.  You are asked for the area between them, which is the difference of the z scores.

Comment: For 13. After i get  18.275 - 14 /1.9 = 2.25  and 9.725-14= -2.25 what do i do?

Comment: So you need to be within $\pm 2.25 \sigma$ of the mean.  Rereading the question, you are not given the normal distribution, so you are expected to use [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)  For 14, you do just what you did above for 13 and report those z-scores

Comment: Sorry, i never got back here to say this sooner, but i really appreciated your help! your direction really made a huge difference!